# Magento different price for each store

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I can change the Price to be Global/ per Website from here: System > Configuration > Catalog > Price.

I have a website with multiple stores.
I want to set a diffrent price (diffrent attributes, not only price) for each store.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`innoext` has created free extension for `store price`

Click [here](http://innoexts.com/promotion/store-view-pricing/#.UO-RuHfcXyQ) to get that

They says it will work for only `Meganto V 1.5.0.1, 1.5.1.0, 1.6.0.0, 1.6.1.0, 1.6.2.0.`

But it work for `Magento V 7 also`..

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice free extension to set different prices for products in different stores.[Check it here](http://innoexts.com/promotion/store-view-pricing/)